# Удаляю Image с канваса Destroy'ем он пропадает но его часть там висит все равно

Tags: c#, unity3d

Остается часть в виде наименования картинки, которая в себе ничего не содержит, я так понимаю это GemeObject остается? И как ее удалить?

```
img = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1];

Destroy(img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном вами коде идет получение компонента в объектах типа `Image`, и затем вы удаляете именно этот компонент с `GameObject`. Другие компоненты этого `GameObject` и сам `GameObject` при этом остаются дальше жить на сцене.  Для того, чтобы уничтожить объект целиком, вам нужно вызвать метод `Destroy()` для самого `GameObject`, а не для компонента. Для этого у объектов, унаследованных от `MonoBehaviour` есть свойство `.gameobject`. Удостовериться в этом можно по [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)

Comment: То есть получать надо `img = transform.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1];` ?

Comment: если надо удалить объект целиком, то получать компонент необязательно, достаточно Destroy(transform.gameObject);

Comment: Надо так `img = Destroy(img.gameobject);`

Answer (score 0):

Вы удаляете компонент, а судя по описанию нужно удалить весь объект
Используйте

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
Destroy(gameObject);
```